# Matlab generate variable names when subdividing large data

Tags: matlab

I have a large data set (vector) I want to split up in to n smaller sets to look at later with other scripts. I.e.if n = 10 I want to turn one 1x80000000 double in to ten 1x8000000 doubles. My thoughts are turn the original in to a n by m matrix then save each row of the matrix in to it's own vector, as follows.

```
%data-n-splitter
n = 10 %number of sections
L = length(data);
Ls = L/n;
Ls = floor(Ls);
Counter = 1;

%converting vector to matrix
datamatrix = zeros(n,Ls);
for k = 1:n
 datamatrix(k,:) = data(Counter:Counter+ Ls - 1);
 Counter = Counter + Ls;
end
```

How do I make matlab loop this part of the code n times:

```
%save each row of matrix as seperate vector

P1 = datamatrix(1,:);
P2 = datamatrix(2,:);
P3 = datamatrix(3,:);
P4 = datamatrix(4,:);
P5 = datamatrix(5,:);
P6 = datamatrix(6,:);
P7 = datamatrix(7,:);
P8 = datamatrix(8,:);
P9 = datamatrix(9,:);
P10 = datamatrix(10,:);
```

Example answer that I'm hoping for:

```
for k = 1:n
P('n') = datamatrix(n,:);
end
```

I've seen some articles about using cell arrays but the scripts I'm passing the variables to aren't set up for this so I'd rather not go down that route if possible.

Comment: Don’t do this. Please read [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval) for good arguments against and good alternatives. “the scripts I'm passing the variables to aren't set up for this” If you have scripts that are set up for dynamic variable names, you should probably rewrite the scripts, it’ll save a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: What's wrong with `datamatrix(n,:)`? It's simple, logical, compact, reusable, maintainable... I don't see any downside to it. Creating `n` separate variables is none of those things.

Comment: Cris I need cut the data down in some way, Matlab, even run through my uni's supercomputer can't crunch the numbers on the entire dataset.

Comment: Beaker it's the name of the variable that's the problem, Matlab isn't happy with P(n).

Comment: Cris I need you to reopen this because I don't have the answer I need.

Comment: @user2587726 If you don't put @ in front of my name, I'm not notified. If your problem is that you insist on using `P(n)` instead of `datamatrix(n,:)` or even `P(n,:)`, then just put each row of `datamatrix` into a cell array called `P`. Then you can call each row vector using `P(n)`. By the way,  it would be a lot easier to create `datamatrix` using `reshape`.

Comment: The linked answer does exactly as you need. It says `eval(['x', num2str(i), ' = ', num2str(i)])`. You just need to adapt it a bit to assign `datamatrix(i,:)` rather than `i`. Yes, it's ugly. I really, really don't want you to do this, but it seems you cannot be swayed.

Comment: I think the lesson I've learnt here is to just not suggest what I think is the start of the answer to the problem I have - it seems to make everyone focus on that bit of code rather than the problem. Speaking to Adrian on the other thread (now deleted) we discussed this and came up with the actual answer I've now posted in the question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo see prev. comment.

Comment: I’ve re-read the question another two times, I don’t see how what you added answers the question at all. There’s no indication at all in your question that you want to save data to a file. I guess not knowing proper terminology makes it really hard to search for solutions on Google too. My best recommendation to you, and I say this with best intentions in mind, is to pick up a book about programming MATLAB, that way you not only pick up the programming itself, but also the terminology that you need to search on Google and communicate with your fellow programmers.

Comment: I have updated the dupe target to a more appropriate Q&A for your actual problem. It has many different answers that are useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

- use a `struct`, which comes closest to what you are hoping for,
- use a `cell`, more convenient looping but no access over meaningful names,
- use a higher-dimension matrix (in your case it is only 2D, but the same applies for 3D or higher). This is the most memory-efficient option.
- To round this off, you could also use a `table`, which is a hybrid of a `struct` and a `cell` as you can use both notations to access it. There is no other benefit.

Now, how to do this? The simplest (and best) solution first: **create a 2D matrix** with `reshape`

```
Ary = 1:10; % I shrank your 1x80000000 array to 1x10 but you'll get the idea
%% create new structure
Mat = reshape(Ary,5,2);
%% access new structure (looping over columns)
for i = 1:size(Ary,2)
   % access columns through slicing
   ary_sct = Mat(:,i);
   % do something
end
```

**Pro**: memory efficient (requires the same amount of memory as the initial array); easy looping

**Con**: only works if you can slice the initial array evenly

Next: **create a cell**

```
Ary = 1:10;
n = 2; % number of sections
L = floor(length(Ary)/n);
% allocate memory
C = cell(1,n);
%% create new structure
for i = 1:n
    % access the content of a cell with {}
    C{i} = Ary((i-1)*L+1:i*L);
end
%% access new structure (looping over entries)
for i = 1:length(C)
    % access the content of a cell with {}
    ary_sct = C{i};
    % do something
end
```

**Pro**: You can store anything in a cell. Every data type and -- what is often more important -- of any dimension

**Con**: The accessing the content (through `{}`) or accessing the element (through `()`) is a bit annoying if your are a beginner; each element require a memory overhead of about 60 bytes as those are pointers, which need to store the information where and on what they are pointing.

Next: **use a struct**

```
Ary = 1:10;
n = 2; % number of sections
L = floor(length(Ary)/n);
% create empty struct
S = struct();
%% create new structure
for i = 1:n
    % create fieldname (must start with a character!)
    fld = num2str(i,'F%d');
    % write to field (note the brackets)
    S.(fld) = Ary((i-1)*L+1:i*L);
end
%% access new structure (looping over fieldnames)
% get all field names
FlNms = fieldnames(S);
for i = 1:length(FldNames)
    % access field names (this is a cell!)
    fld = FldNms{i};
    % access struct
    ary_sct = S.(fld);
    % do something
end
```

**Pro**: Field names are convenient to keep the overview of your data

**Con**: accessing field names in a loop is a bit tedious; each element require a memory overhead of about 60 bytes as those are pointers, which need to store the information where and on what they are pointing.

Comment: Whilst this answer is helpful, you've not actually answered what I need.

I need to save down the different "subvariables" once I've split it up, which is why I need the variable names to change.

Comment: your code does not suggest that you want to save/load something -- acknowledged, which contradicts a bit to the title^^. So what is your problem with using `save`/`load`? You can specify which variable to `load` and you can load everything into a `struct`, of which you now know how to access it;)

Comment: "split up in to n smaller sets to look at later" ... "turn the original in to a n by m matrix then save each row of the matrix in to it's own vector"...

Comment: I think the lesson I've learnt here is to just not suggest what I think is the start of the answer to the problem I have - it seems to make everyone focus on that rather than the problem.

Comment: @user2587726 that's not the case, please do keep suggesting solutions yourself! The main issue was, as we discussed in chat yesterday, the use of different terminology. What you called **variables** were actually **files**, which makes a vast difference in how you'd solve it. This is what I mentioned to you in chat, and which is why this answer is actually the answer to your question, as was the initial dupe, because they deal with **variables**. Don't get disheartened by people asking you for clarification, because it can root out these kind of confusions.